# Has any Catholic been knighted in the UK in recent history?

Tags: united-kingdom, europe, religion

In the past 50-100 years, has a British monarch knighted anyone of self-professed Catholic persuation?

This question is about English Church influence on English establishment. Has anyone of the Catholic religion been knighted?

**Context note:**  I asked this question around the time of minor controversy caused by Markle's conversion.  While it was clear that the British society had become welcoming of many religions and creeds, it remained unclear how the relationship to the royals' family had changed with respect to acceptance of Catholics to its inner circle.

Comment: This seems a very odd question. Catholic emancipation began in 1766, following the death of the last Jacobite claimant to the throne. There are not only catholic knights, but plenty of members of the peerage, and at least one duke, namely the Duke of Norfolk.

Comment: @WS2, Your comment past the 1st sentence would be a good answer.  As for the sentiment of the 1st sentence, you may think that this is a non-issue issue, but the fact is that a headline about a Catholic geting knighted merited mentioning that he is, in fact, a Catholic.  The fact that you know that there are members of peerage who are Catholic, and a Duke who is a Catholic, point to the fact that normalization of Catholicism in GB is of historical and political significance.  No one would ask if there were Catholic US Congressmen, for example.  That would be an odd question.

Comment: @grovkin The article about the Catholic composer getting knighted is from the "Catholic Herald." It's like how an article from a college newspaper about an alum would mention that they're an alum.

Comment: @grovkin I don't agree. I well remember when John F.Kennedy was running for the presidency, how many thought a Roman Catholic would never hold the office, and what a big moment for Catholics when he did. Remember that America has never had a Jewish president, nor a female president - ground that Britain broke long ago. Also remember that Gt Britain's was effectively a country founded by protestantism in the late-seventeenth century. It was a crucial defining element of the national identity

Comment: @WS2 and that was so long ago that people, in fact, don't remember it. The current SCOTUS didn't have a single Protestant until Gorsuch and no one even bat an eye about the Jewish/Catholic composition of the court until Gorsuch was being confirmed. It just wasn't an issue. US had Catholic members of the government as far back as the Continental Congress. I think 2 of the Federalists were Catholic. There was never any legal issue precluding Catholics from serving in office. Presidents having been all Protestants was more a reflection of who the majority of the people were than anything in law.

Comment: @WS2, but to make the long story even shorter, Kennedy didn't have to abandon Catholicism to become President.  Markle converted even though "she didn't have to."  Markle converted to keep with traditions.  Had Kennedy converted, it would have been seen as blatanly unconstituional violation on the prohibition on religious test for public office.  So in Kennedy's case, the tradition would have been violated if he had converted.  Since the timing of this question is so close to Markle's converstion, it's not so odd to ask how far do these traditions extend into the public life of the Queen.

Comment: @grovkin, I did a little research into whether Macmillan's Catholicicism was considered particularly remarkable or notable in the context of the knighthood. Answer updated.

Comment: Well Knighthood is not dependent on the religious faith of a person. Stephen Hawking (who calls himself an atheist) was approached for Knighthood in 1990's but he rejected the Knighthood because of U.K.'s science funding problems. Link - http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/new-year-honours-from-nigella-lawson-to-stephen-hawking-the-people-who-have-previously-declined-a6791796.html

Comment: @grovkin If you had mentioned Markle's conversion as the context for your question, I would have understood where you were coming from. Without knowing what I would consider an obscure piece of royal trivia, I did think it a somewhat random question. To be perfectly fair though, Tony Blair was flirting with Catholicism when he was a serving Prime Minister, and that did raise a few eyebrows.

Comment: @richardb Re Tony Blair. Perhaps only within the context of his negotiating the Belfast agreement. His wife was always a Catholic, and he has of course since become one himself.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand UK government perfectly, but isn't this an official government act with legal ramifications? If there was official discrimination against a religion it would certainly be on topic. Could someone explain the close vote?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Is what "an official government act with legal ramifications"?

Comment: @WS2 Knighting someone. I suggest knighting is a political act by a government, which I would expect to be clearly on topic, and note that none of the voters commented why it is not.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt You really need to read up on the British honours system. In theory all honours, of which knighthoods are only one, are awarded by the monarch. It is not only the government who recommend people for honours, recommendations come from the other political parties too. The whole process is certainly not subject to any legal act, but is inherent in Britain's unwritten, aged, and slightly arcane constitution - based on principles of precedent and convention. It does become a subject of public interest and heated argument from time to time.

Comment: @WS2, in what way does anything in your comment suggest that being knighted has nothing to do with the British government?

Comment: @grovkin Did I say it "had nothing to do with the British government"?

Comment: @WS2, you replied to a comment which gave justification for why this was about the government. And your reply seemed to suggest that you didn't think that comment was on point. This action suggested you were contradicting the comment that this question was about the British government. If that's not what you meant to say, then ok. But then I don't know what was the point of telling someone that they should educate themselves more (if not to piont out that their statement didn't agree with what you know to be true).

Comment: @grovkin Well the commenter said that "knighting is a political act by a government". When I suggested they read up on the honours system, I meant they would discover that it was a far more complicated matter than that. In theory (but only in theory) the Queen is the government. In so far as she awards the honour - yes the person is  awarded the knighthood by the government.  But the all-important "recommendations" for honours come not only from the Prime Minister, but from the leader of HM Loyal Opposition too - as well as from other parties, and from Civil Service lists.

Comment: @WS2, this might a case of 2 countries separated by a common language.  In American parlance, "government worker" refers to anyone who works for any service administered by the government (and for any of the branches of government).  So a postworker can describe himself as a "government employee."  Certainly any elected member of the British Parliament would be a government member in that sense (even if they are not a "member of the government", as a ruling body, in the parliamentary sense of the term).

Comment: @WS2, the difference probably makes more sense if you take into account the fact that the executive and the legislative branches are elected completely separately and the excutive does not need to "form a government" when elected.  So a President's party being in a minority in either house of Congress is fairly normal and does not change how the government functions.  Members of minority and majority in both legislative houses are all considered government members by the virtue of being Congress members.

Comment: @grovkin I fear we may have strayed from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Has any Catholic been knighted by GB in recent history?**

Yes.

For example [Catholic composer James MacMillan knighted](http://catholicherald.co.uk/news/2015/06/15/catholic-composer-james-macmillan-knighted/), 2015.

Also atheists, [Moslems, Jews](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk/4081534.stm), [Hindus](http://www.thehindu.com/news/international/British-Indian-professor-knighted-in-New-Year%E2%80%99s-honours/article16969506.ece) etc, the honour is not reserved for people of any specific faith.

---

> **a headline about a Catholic geting knighted merited mentioning that he is, in fact, a Catholic**

That may be because I found him by searching for something like "Catholic Knighthood" - it was likely that the first relevant headline 
would include my search terms.

Although he is a well-known Catholic, noted for its influence in his music, you have to search hard to find anyone else who considers Macmillan's Catholicism worth remarking on in the context of a knighthood:

- UK Gov: [The Queen’s Birthday Honours List 2015](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/434644/Birthday_Honours_2015_Higher_Awards_citations.pdf)

  > Dr. James Loy Macmillan CBE. Dr. Macmillan is a composer and conductor of international renown. He has retained his distinctiveness as a composer inspired by religious faith and he is also active as a working parish church musician in education and community work. His music was the focus of the 
  >   London Symphony Orchestra’s 2009/10 Artist Portrait season, where his violin concerto was premiered alongside performances of his trumpet concerto 
  >   Epiclesis and an education project Into the Ferment. He has served as Composer/Conductor of the BBC Philharmonic and remains Principal Guest Conductor of the Netherlands Radio Kamer Filharmonie.
- BBC Scotland: [Scots recognised in Queen's Birthday Honours](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-33114014)

  > Scots from all walks of life have been recognised in the Queen's Birthday Honours list. They include composer James MacMillan, who is to be knighted
- Music Newsmedium: [Classical musicians recognised in Queen’s Birthday Honours 2015](http://www.rhinegold.co.uk/choir_organ/archive-2277/)

  > James MacMillan, Karl Jenkins and Simon Halsey are
  >   among the classical musicians to be recognised in the Queen’s Birthday Honours list for 2015. MacMillan, who was made a CBE in 2004, has received
  >   a knighthood for services to music. The composer, conductor and festival
  >   director considers his Scottish roots to be of great importance; the first Cumnock Tryst festival took place in his Ayrshire home town last year, and his works bear the influence of Gaelic folk music.
- Scottish Christians: [James MacMillan leads knighted Scots](https://scottishchristian.com/queens-birthday-honours-james-macmillan-leads-knighted-scots/)

  > Composer James MacMillan has said he is “totally delighted” at being knighted in the Queen’s Birthday Honours list.
  >   The 55-year-old has been awarded the honour for services to music.
  >   Dr MacMillan’s music is widely performed around the world by performers ranging from top international orchestras to local church and community choirs.
  >   One of his compositions was a new choral piece which was sung when Pope Benedict XVI conducted mass at Bellahouston Park in Glasgow in 2010.  ...
  >   *[no explicit mention of Catholicism]*

It seems that regional or niche media tend to mention that the subject is "one of us", even when it would otherwise be unremarkable. He's not the first musician to have been knighted, nor the first scot.

This actually makes it harder to answer the original question. You can't tell if no blue-eyed left-handers are allowed to be knighted - because those factors are almost never reported. More likely they are not reported because thay are not relevant or significant (in this context) than because there is an anti-blue-eyed-left-hander bias or rule in the UK establishment.

Answer (score -4):

While I was thinking about [RegGrittyBrick's excellent answer to this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/28403/13162), I realized that the composer he mentioned had a name starting with "Mac".  I began to suspect that most names starting with "Mac" or "Mc" indicate that they were Catholic and that this indicated that MacMillan was Catholic without mentioning it directly.  After a little googling, *this suspicion was proven wrong*.  This, as is turned out, was a common misunderstanding.

But the thinking about this name got me to recall another famous composer whose name started with "Mc", who is probably one of the most famous composers of the 20th century, who was baptized Catholic, and who was knighted -- **Sir Paul McCartney** (of the Beatles).

This kind of made me think that the question may have been a bit out there.  Given the current politics surrounding Markle baptism, it's at least a little apropo. I'll leave it open, but with this answer attached.

Comment: Mac and Mc are both part of a Celtic naming pattern meaning "son of", and are fairly common across Scotland and Ireland (both North and the Republic). While some families in those regions are Catholic, some are really, really not.

Comment: @origimbo, I got that it was a common misunderstanding from the googling (as the answer already mentions).  Didn't know it meant "son of".  Interesting!

Comment: Within the Commonwealth, I'm not even sure I'd go as far as calling it common, although things are complicated by the UK viewpoint that religion is a private matter people generally won't discuss. I'd put it on the same level as assuming anyone with the name Singh must be Sikh.

Comment: The assumption that someone with the name Singh is Sikh is quite reliable as that is a name normally adopted in connection with affirmation of a religious identity. The historical state religion of Scotland is Presbyterian, and lots of Scots are Mac, so this is almost an anti-correlation based upon the fact that many Irish who also often have Mac in a name are Catholic.